# Aggregate Exception with Parallel.For on Bitmap Array

Tags: c#, bitmap, parallel.for

I have method operating on a 4x2 array of bitmap images, and I'm using a Parallel.For to loop thru each of the 8 images. It then loops thru each pixel in each image and modifies each pixel in each of those images, and returns the completed bitmap array.

When I run the app it generates the array fine, but when it gets to this code I  get an "Aggregate Exception", but from that error I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

Could some kind person see if anything obvious sticks out in this code? Thanks.

```
public Bitmap[,] ParallelImageProcess(Bitmap[,] bmap)
    {

        Parallel.For(0, 3, y =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                int width = bmap[x, y].Width;
                int height = bmap[x, y].Height;

                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                    {
                        Color oldPixel = bmap[x, y].GetPixel(i, j);
                        Color newPixel = Color.FromArgb(oldPixel.R, oldPixel.G, 0);
                        bmap[x, y].SetPixel(i, j, newPixel);
                    }

                }

            }

        });
        return bmap;
    }
```

Comment: Inspect the `AggregateException` - it's simply a wrapper around the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, will do. But I guess my question was more of a generic question regarding applying a Parallel.For to processing every pixel in an image, or a group of images. I'm wondering if the Parallel.For might go crazy with so many "for" operations (and possibly many threads) when processing thousands of pixels in multiple images.

Comment: @Rob My apologies. Without trying to unravel the AggregateException I did some minor detective work I realized I had swapped my x and y indexes, so the For loop was referencing array elements that didn't exist. On the bright side, I found out that Parallel.For works fine in this configuration, even operating on 8 bitmaps. And as expected, even this isn't nearly as fast as LockBits :)